# How can I track a CGPoint of a touch input in a UIView, as the finger moves along the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mkmapview

How can I get a CGPoint of a users touch?

It's actually a MKMapView, but since it inherits from a UIView, I'm thinking it's the same.

I can add a UIGestureRecognizer. But what I'm looking to, is to track the finger's position as it moves in the map view.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a gesture recognizer that uses this handler:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    CGPoint locationInView = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate. I need to track the finger, as it moves on the screen. I can't seem to be able to do this with a UIGestureRecognizer?

Comment: That did it! Thank you. I also did needed the UIPanGestureRecognizer. Thank you.

Comment: Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer: `[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];` and attach it to the view that you want to track.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation below updates the coordinates when you drag and touches on the screen.

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint coordinate = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    self.coordinateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f",coordinate.x,coordinate.y];
}
```

Comment: I need to track the finger's position, as it moves along the view.

Comment: Yes, the above code will display the coordinates of your finger when moving on the UIView. Just paste the code in your UIViewController and try it out. Instead of a UILabel use NSLog to print out the coordinates.